# Как при клике на checkbox выбрать такой же checkbox ( c таким же текстом ) из другого блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть два блока, в них находятся чекбоксы. Мне нужно при выборе чекбокса из одного блока, выбирать такой же ( с таким же текстом ) из второго и при отключение - отключать такой же из второго соответственно.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я это могу реализовать на jquery?

У меня получилось сделать так, чтобы при клике выбирался чекбокс из другого блока, но текущий ( кликнутый ) не выбирается.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.fillings', function (e) {
  console.log('test')
  let itemText = $(this).find('span').text();
  let allItems = $('.fillings');
  
  // выбираем остальные чекбосы с таким же названием
  allItems.each(function(index, item) {
    let text = $(item).find('span').text();

    if (itemText == text) {
      $(item).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    }
  })
})

// отключаю событие от input, так как при клике на label событие отрабатывает два раза
$(document).on('click', '.fillings input', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
})
```

```css
.second-block {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
label {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover {
  color: 
}
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first-block">
  <h3>Первый блок</h3>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Лунный мальчки</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Тесто лунной стрекозы</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Вафельный биксвит
лунного света</span>
  </label>
</div>

<h3>Второй блок</h3>
<div class="second-block">
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Вафельный биксвит
лунного света</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Лунный мальчки</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Тесто лунной стрекозы</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/IvanGrishov/pen/NWXLmVM?editors=1111

Comment: Предположительно нужно убрать e.stopPropagation() и должно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ремарочка. Старайтесь обрабатывать события непосредственно на элементах. Когда Вы прослушиваете событие на всём документе во первых, вы заставляете слушателя перебирать весь DOM, чтобы найти элемент, во вторых на документе слишком много слушателей могут приводить к нежелаемому поведению.

```js
$('.fillings').click(function (e) {
  let chkd = $(this).find('input:checked')[0]?true:false; 
  let fillings = $('.fillings');
  let itemText = $(this).find('span').text(); 
   fillings.each(function(evt) {
     let thisText = $(this).find('span').text();
     let thisInput = $(this).find('input');
     if (thisText==itemText) {
       chkd?thisInput.prop('checked', true): thisInput.prop('checked', false);
     }//закомментируйте этот if и раскомментируйте следующее выражение, в зависимости от того, что вам надо;
     //thisText==itemText&&chkd?thisInput.prop('checked', true): thisInput.prop('checked', false);
   })
 })
```

```css
.second-block {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
span {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
label {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover {
  color: 
}
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h3 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-block">
  <h3>Первый блок</h3>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Лунный мальчки</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Тесто лунной стрекозы</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Вафельный биксвит
лунного света</span>
  </label>
</div>

<h3>Второй блок</h3>
<div class="second-block">
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Вафельный биксвит
лунного света</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Лунный мальчки</span>
  </label>
  <label class="fillings">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span>Тесто лунной стрекозы</span>
  </label>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```